# Traceroute hops in the same subnet

Tags: networking, router, subnet, traceroute

in what case is there two neighbor hops in the same subnet in a traceroute output? As I know it should be only source addresses and each router interface should be in different subnet?

E.g.:

```
1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
2     2 ms     3 ms    <3 ms  10.10.0.14
3     5 ms     4 ms     3 ms  10.10.0.15
4     21 ms    22 ms    25 ms  194.221.100.49
```

It should look something like this.

```
(PC) 192.168.1.2 --- 192.168.1.1 (Router1) 10.10.0.X --- 10.10.0.14 (Router2) 10.10.0.x --- 10.10.0.15 (Router3) 192.221.100.X --- 192.221.100.49 (Router4) X.X.X.X
```

But in Router2 there are 2 interfaces in the same subnet, which should not be possible?

What kind of configuration it might be? Maybe Frame Relay?

Comment: Is the origin also in the 10.10.0.0/24 network?

Comment: No it is not.  It's 192.168 network.

Comment: It would be hard to say without seeing the topology.  You can configure routers to reply from any address you like with a bit of NAT, but it may be simpler.  Lets say you have two routers with interfaces on the same 10.10.0.0 network.  Your route to 194.221.100.49 is via 10.10.0.14, and its route to it is via 10.10.0.15.  Is that first `1.` genuine?

Comment: No it's not. I edited my question, now it has the real output.

Comment: Traceroute replies are sent from the interface that routes back to you.  So it isn't necessarily true that router 1 and router 2 are linked via the 10.10.0.0 network, they might be linked using an entirely different network, but both have interfaces on the 10.10.0.0 network

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> each router interface should be in different subnet?

The error in your logic lies in the assumption that network topologies always involve routers which strictly pass packets received on an interface in one subnetwork out via an interface defined in a different subnetwork. While that is true in common SOHO and medium-enterprise environments, it is not the *only* possible mode of deployment available. Network engineers might have reasons to adopt another approach, or through luck and configuration churn, they might cause one to be adopted accidentally.

There are several scenarios in which a router can receive packets which are subsequently routed back to the same network they were received on. It matters how and with reference to which device that we define our subnets. For example, it is entirely legal for a router to have an interface of `10.0.0.1/16`, while devices sat behind it use addresses in the subnet `10.0.x.y/24`. From the device's perspective, packets from 10.0.1.x to 10.0.2.x would need to traverse one or more routers, but the router knows better. This phenomenon of [network tromboning](http://blog.ipspace.net/2011/02/traffic-trombone-what-it-is-and-how-you.html) is commonly found in the core of enterprise networks. While not necessarily efficient, it does work and the router is doing its job correctly.

Another common occurrence occurs when running a traceroute from a device connected to a VPN concentrator, which tunnels its traffic over the VPN to the remote device. If we suppose this was the cause of your traceroute output, the `.14` device would likely be the concentrator connected to the corporate LAN at the remote end. The `.15` device is the router for the network the concentrator is connected to. Packets are received (tunnelled) on the `.14` interface, and passed back out the same interface to be routed onwards to their destination. There's nothing wrong with this, and `traceroute` is legitimately showing you the identities of all the devices responsible for touching the packets at the IP layer.

Without further precise knowledge of the network topology, and in particular the configuration of the intermediate router(s), it is impossible to understand precisely what is occurring in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Traceroute works by effectively sending a ping with a TTl (time to live) of 1. It hits the first router which replies with an ICMP Time Exceeded message. It repeats this, in your case a total of 3 times.

Then it sends 3 pings with a TTL of 2, then 3 etc. It displays each router's response as a route to the host.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute

My first guess is that if your system is configured properly then your first router (which is configured not to send the Time Exceeded message) has a default path to 10.10.0.14 which has a static route declared to the 194.221.100.49 subnet

Comment: Sorry typo: ...which has a static route declared to the 194.221.100.49 subnet via the 10.10.0.15 router.